# how to delete line breaks in String read from a pdf file in java

Tags: java

I use pdfbox to read a PDF file and I want to delete the line breaks in a string. I have used

```
 string = string.replaceAll("/n|/r|/t", "");
```

but it doesn't work. Please help me.

[this is the string from pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yQUI.png)

Comment: You probably want "\\n" instead of "/n" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, we use the backslash `\` (not the forward slash `/`) to escape characters within a string. So you should use:

```
string.replaceAll("\\n|\\r|\\t", "");
```